# "Unable to locate JAR/zip" error for JDBC connections [BIRT Eclipse, Windows 7, Oracle 11g]

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, oracle11g, driver, birt

As an FYI, I'm new to this entire stack, so I might be making a basic error.

I'm attempting to explore BIRT reporting for a Maximo system that was recently upgraded.

To do so, I installed the following:

- Java 6 & Java 7 JDKs
- BIRT version of Eclipse (Eclipse + BIRT plugins built in).
- Some Oracle 11gR2 client options (a custom install)

  - SQL*Plus
  - JDBC/ODBC drivers
  - Thin Client

I take the following steps:

- Open Eclipse
- Create a new Reporting Project
- Add a Data Source
- Select "JDBC Data Source" (also tried "JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder")
- Select the "Oracle" connection profile type and click next.

At this point, I see that the drivers list is empty. This strikes me as odd, but I figure maybe I have to define the driver definition. So I take the following steps:

- Click "Define driver definition"
- In the Name/Type tab, select "Oracle Thin Driver", system version 11

At this point, I see an error message: **Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: ojdbc14.jar**. It seems that ojdbc14.jar doesn't even exist on my system that I can find.

I have tried adding other jdbc jar files that I can find in the oracle client directory (i.e. from Oracle_Base\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib) but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Help?

Comment: Remove the pre-existing ojdbc14.jar from the list of jars, and add yours, from your oracle install.

Comment: Hi JB -- as far as I know, I have tried adding ever .jar I could find under the Oracle install directory, just to be sure. I will look again tomorrow when back in the office and update. Thanks!

Comment: @goober: Have you tried amending the driver definition when running Birt from a clean start (`eclipse.exe -clean`)? I have occasionally found this useful when experiencing driver trouble.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had similar issue.
Clicking "Clear all" and then adding the jar manually solved the problem.

Comment: Changing the correct answer to this one because it appears both easier and also like it worked more for others.

Answer (score 3):

The answer in this case was unfortunately stupidly simple -- after closing and reopening Eclipse, I had no trouble removing the driver, adding another, and getting to work. I was up and running in no time.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the ojdbc14.jar file exsists and is in your library path. When on the dialog for picking the driver ojdbc14.jar, simply click the find jar/zip button and find the file.
Sometimes it is there, but still does not work. To solve this problem, press the "clear all" button. Now repeat the above process. The .jar will be added and you will continue to driver connection and details dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Eclipse IDE could not find the driver in the eclipse installation path. This is what you will do:
Search for the .jar file in your system and copy it to the eclipse installation path.
If you could not get it visit http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j and locate the required connector. Download it and save it to the eclipse installation path. So now Eclipse can see it and the error would no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer is Into the Jar Console Click on edit jar and Again select jar in your file system. that will locate file in your file system simple

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart Eclipse and start again with the process: Database Connections -> New -> PostgreSQL -> Clear All (JAR list) -> Load the jar again.

This way it worked correctly.